# Error MyApplication Execution failed for task ':app:kaptDebugKotlin'

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-room

I have an error in MyApplication, every time I see that I build the project it appears, I think it has to do with the room but I can't solve it

Log:

```
Task :app:kaptDebugKotlin FAILED
C:\Users\matheus.correa_est\Desktop\Pokedex- 
master\app\build\tmp\kapt3\stubs\debug\com\example\pokedex\MyApplication.java:13: error: cannot find 
symbol
    public final AppDataBase getDataBase() {
                 ^
  symbol:   class AppDataBase
  location: class MyApplication
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:kaptDebugKotlin'.
> A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptExecution
   > java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException (no error message)

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more 
log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.5/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 2s
24 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 23 up-to-date
```

MyApplication.java

```
package com.example.pokedex;

import java.lang.System;

d2 = {"Lcom/example/pokedex/MyApplication;", "Landroid/app/Application;", "()V", "dataBase", 
"LAppDataBase;", "getDataBase", "()LAppDataBase;", "dataBase$delegate", "Lkotlin/Lazy;", 
"repository", "Lcom/example/pokedex/repository/PokedexRepository;", "getRepository", " 
()Lcom/example/pokedex/repository/PokedexRepository;", "repository$delegate", "app_debug"})
public class MyApplication extends android.app.Application {
    @org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull()
    private final kotlin.Lazy dataBase$delegate = null;
    @org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull()
    private final kotlin.Lazy repository$delegate = null;

    @org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull()
    public final AppDataBase getDataBase() {   //  line where the error is being shown in the log
        return null;
    }

    @org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull()
    public final com.example.pokedex.repository.PokedexRepository getRepository() {
        return null;
    }

    public MyApplication() {
        super();
    }
}
```

class AppDatabase

```
@Database(entities = [PokemonItem::class], version = 1, exportSchema = false)
abstract class AppDataBase: RoomDatabase() {
abstract fun pokemonDAO(): PokemonDAO

companion object {
    @Volatile
    private var INSTANCE: AppDataBase? = null
    fun getDataBase(context: Context): AppDataBase {
        return INSTANCE ?: synchronized(this) {
            val instance = Room.databaseBuilder(
                context.applicationContext,
                AppDataBase::class.java,
                "pokemon-db"
            )
                .build()
            INSTANCE = instance
            instance
        }
    }
   }
 }
```

this error started to happen since I put the AppDatabase to do data persistence, I thought the problem was in the gradle but from what I saw I couldn't fix it by its version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved, the class was out of the package, for this reason it was not importing and so, I was pointing out the error

```
package com.example.pokedex.dao
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks very wrong. Just follow google document:

https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working example of a vary basic App that has a mix of Kotlin and Java and includes a Room database. It is based upon the rudimentary idea/intent of your code. You could then expand upon this.

The **PokemonItem** Entity (table) class in Kotlin :-

```
@Entity
class PokemonItem {
    @PrimaryKey
    var id: Long? = null
    var name: String = ""
}
```

The **PokemonDao** interface (Kotlin) with just a query to extract all (it's use will therefore create the database) :-

```
@Dao
public interface PokemonDao {

    @Query("SELECT * FROM pokemonitem")
    fun getAllFromPokemonItem(): List<PokemonItem>
}
```

A simplified **AppDatabase** abstract class (Kotlin) (not a singleton) :-

```
@Database(entities = arrayOf(PokemonItem::class),version = 1)
abstract class AppDatabase: RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun pokeMonDao(): PokemonDao
}
```

An Activity (Java) that uses the above to extract all (none as none have been added) PokemonItems :-

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    AppDatabase pokemonDB;
    PokemonDao pokemonDao;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        pokemonDB = Room.databaseBuilder(
                this,
                AppDatabase.class,
                "poekmon.db"
        )
                .allowMainThreadQueries()
                .build();
        pokemonDao = pokemonDB.pokeMonDao();
        List<PokemonItem> pokemonItems = pokemonDao.getAllFromPokemonItem();
    }
}
```

**Result**

Running and then using Database Inspector (Android Studio) shows :-

i.e. It has compiled and run and due to the attempt to open the database has created the database.

- Note that .allowMainThreadQueries allows it to run on the main thread and has been included for brevity.

:-

[image]

Comment: After doing the above, I was presented with an error on Main: private AppDataBase pokemonDB;
            ^
  symbol:   class AppDataBase
  location: class MainActivity
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:kaptDebugKotlin'.
> A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptExecution
   > java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException (no error message)